# Django: unable to locate static files folder

Tags: python, django, iis, django-staticfiles

I am trying to setup an AS2 server using the python package **django-pyas2** (https://github.com/abhishek-ram/django-pyas2)

Everything has been working fine while I was using the *runserver* command, but when trying to host my web app using IIS(10), I've noticed that none of my static files get loaded when loading a page.

I've been on countless forums/documentations and I know that I need to setup my IIS to serve these files, but I haven't been able to answer a rather stupid question:

**Where is the */static/* folder of *django-pyas2* located ???**

There is no such folder on the github page.
When using the *runserver* command, django somehow manages to find all the static files (.css, .js, .png) from the static folder, but I am still totally clueless to where that folder is actually stored.

I've been searching in these locations to no avail: (I'm using a virtual env on Windows Server 2016)

- my own project
- my venv's ***site-packages\django-pyas2*** folder
- in ***C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\django-pyas2***
- in ***C:\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\django-pyas2***

I've also tried to use the command *collectstatic*, but I first need to know where the actual */static/* folder is stored.

I've double-checked, and the files are apparently stored locally and not on a CDN. This is driving me kind of nuts, and I could definetly use some help from someone!

A big thanks in advance ❤

EDIT:

[my IIS wfastcgi configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJBPj.png)

[my IIS advanced settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWvcv.png)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: Please post your IIS configuration about Django？ When you publish to IIS, a fastcgi which is mapped python.exe|wfastcgi.py should be spcified. And it should work for any extension. Besides, have you tried to install IIS static content feature?

Comment: @JokiesDing Thanks for your response, i've added my IIS configuration. CGI and static content features are both installed on my IIS. The problem does not really reside in how to configure my IIS, but rather the location of my static folder, which seems to be inexistant on my drives...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how IIS(10) works but this is usually the fix.

go to settings.py and add a path for your static files.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')#new
```

Next on the console (command prompt/ terminal/shell) run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This should work

Comment: When trying your solution, I get the following error message: FileNotFoundError [WinError 3] The specified path was not found: 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\django_pyas2_test\\static'. Which brings me back to my first question: where is the static folder ? I use a package which is supposed to contain said files, but can't find them.

Comment: Can you send the link of your static folder on your GitHub repository?

Comment: Since I couldn't find any static folder, but only a couple of pictures on your GitHub repository I suspect you haven't included a static folder. A good practice would be to have a static folder in you app in Django. The structure would be exactly like the templates folder. ```static/appname/```. Let me know if that works!

Comment: The github I provided in my question is not mine. I don't know how, but the thing works without any static folder when using the command: python manage.py runserver. When inspecting the loded page, all content from http://localhost:8000/static/* is magically loaded, without any means for me to find the true location of the static folder.

Comment: When deploying to a live server and usually under normal circumstances, not having a static folder will make you run into issues. So probably try it with a static folder. Also if that works, can you verify my answer? (by clicking on the tick) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I finally found the static folder I was looking for in this location:

***<PYTHON_PATH>\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static***

I believe the *django_pyas2* package is using some default js/css already included with Django, and I couldn't find it because it was burried in Django's files.

For those encountering the same problem, here are the steps I then took to make it work with IIS(10):

- copy/pasted the static folder from the django package to my project's root
- went to IIS manager, right clicked on my website > **Add Application**
- for the application **alias**: *"static"*, for the **path**: *<path_to_static_folder>*
- **/!\ IMPORTANT /!\** left clicked on newly created "static" application, went to Mapping Manager, and then deleted the associated FastCGIModule

Didn't have to do anything in settings.py, nor execute the collectstatic command.

Works fine after that!

Thanks for trying to help.